# PostgreSQL Database connection issue on RDS with dblink

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-rds

I've two databases on the RDS instance. Let's say db1 and db2.
I'm trying to do a query like this with dblink on db2.

```
SELECT * FROM dblink ( 'dbname=db1 port=5432 host=<host_ip> user=<user> password=<password>', 'select count(*) from my_table' );
```

And getting errors like this:

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "<host_ip>" (IP) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Are these two databases on the same instance?  If so, try 'localhost' for the host.